# Netgear R7000 WAN connection 10Mbps

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

Just got 100Mbps internet service and pulled a Netgear R7000 out of retirement to connect to it. The router started with AdvancedTomato firmware. I noticed my speeds were peaking at 10Mbps. Looking at the router status page, I could see that the port was negotiating at 10Mbps.

A few things I've tried:

- **Different patch cables.** No change.
- **Different router connected to the same Cat5e connector and cable.** The other router speed test comes in at about 103Mbps.
- **Computer connected directly to the jack.** Same result as connecting a different router.
- **Different firmwares.** I've tried the AdvancedTomato that was on the router originally, the latest official firmware, and the latest DD-WRT firmware, all with the same result.
- **Connecting the router to other devices.** When I had the AdvancedTomato firmware and could easily see the speed the port had negotiated, I connected the router's WAN port to my desktop computer's Gigabit ethernet controller using the same patch cable, and the status page reported 1000Mbps connectivity on the router's WAN port.

I had this router connected to Comcast service previously and was able to achieve >10Mbps speeds. It's only now connected to my WaveG service that it can't seem to negotiate more than 10Mbps with this one device.

I'm not sure where to go with this issue. It seems as though there's nothing wrong with my router since it gets gigabit connectivity when connected to my computer. It seems there's nothing wrong with the jack or anything behind it since other devices can get >100Mbps speeds connected to it. The cable seems to be fine since it works with other devices. I've tried every alternative firmware I'm aware of in addition to the official firmware.

I don't really want to buy a new router since that doesn't seem to be the problem. Where can I go from here?

Comment: Guess I am not sure why you think the router is not the problem, it clearly seems to be... perhaps problem isn't the right word here though, but incompatibility. Working for an ISP we have seen this before, it is rare but sometimes there is a just an issue where gigabit doesn't want to negotiate properly between two devices, occasionally falling to 100Mbps, and often to 10Mbps/Half-Duplex. The solution is replace one end or the other (router or modem) or put something in between, like a small 5-port gigabit switch.

Comment: @acejavelin I agree with you. An unmanaged switch would work for that, right? I think I'll order one and give it a shot.

Comment: Yes, should be fine.